# Issue while push the code from branch to sandbox

Tags: metadata-api, eclipse, xml

I faced an issue 'valueSettings invalid at this Location  in type picklist'.Could you please help me out from this issue.

Thank you.

regards,

Suresh

Comment: Please compare your picklist value in source org and your target org

Comment: Hi Annappa I have compare the code and in souorce org i used </valueSet> <value></value></valueSet> in source org, if i use same for move to branch ,i faced issue,So i updated that with <picklist><picklistValues></picklistValues></picklist> then the issue resolved,Now i have another one  <valueSettings> ,here i face the above mention issue,i need to replace this with any other tag,that what i'm searching for,if you have any information about it please share with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your comment:

According to this: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_picklist.htm (outdated docs)

You'll need to replace `<valueSettings></valueSettings>` (which is used for dependant picklists)
also with `<picklistValues></picklistValues>`

But your main issue is diffrent api version.
Your target org is probably on spring18 (so api version 42) and your source org is on summer 18 (api version 43)

To resolve it you can for example refresh your destination org (or if it is production refresh source sandbox)

Comment: Yes ,it is API version issue,i have updated my version now working. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please mark answer as accepted then :)